# How is this web resource hidden from the user?

Tags: web-browser, chrome, drm

**Motivation:** I've been interested in how various agencies hide data, either through incompetence or willful intent, that is required to be "open". Specifically I've seen oil companies use images to display their transparency reports and financial companies display data via massive time-delayed queries to prevent scraping. Recently, I encountered a new method, this time implemented as a pseudo-DRM:

**Question:** How does myfont.com hide the font from the browser? Can it be defeated?

**Research:** Consider the page for the font [Modern Brush](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/street-type/modern-brush/webfont_preview.html). It showcases a webfont for sale. Under Chrome's developer tools there are several fonts listed:

[image]

but none of the fonts look like the font used on screen. The fonts are clearly loaded however, since there is an editable div:

```
<div contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false" 
  class="text headline" 
  data-font="Modern Brush" 
  style="font-family: 'Modern Brush';">
            The Wonder of Webfonts
</div>
```

and a corresponding CSS style:

[image]

**Close votes:** I think that understanding this particular technique falls under the purview of SE Information Security. Additionally, please note that this question asks for information on circumventing a DRM (even if the intent is pedagogic). These reasons may constitute a reason for closing. If so, please advise in the comments.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're having trouble.  I was able to grab a copy in TrueType format with just a little poking around using `wget`.  I was also able to get Embedded OpenType and WOFF2 files, but I don't have the ability to verify that those files actually have the correct font.

Comment: Wonder whether other resources can be hidden like that. I mean, what if you can hide a malicious JS like that? Or exploited image. Oh, there may even be ttf-exploit hidden like that in the wild

Comment: @НЛО I think that is an interesting point and maybe grounds for an additional question. If you do ask it, can you provide a comment here linking them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font files are loaded via CSS using code similar to this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Modern Brush';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url('/url-here/') format('woff');
}
```

I'm not convinced they have tried to hide this at all. The woff font file loaded shows up under the fonts tab in FireBug ok. The preview fails though as it doesn't factor in the URL parameters `Key-Pair-Id`, `Policy` and `Signature` which obviously make a difference, and presumably therefore these are components of their DRM implementation.

Comment: You mean Fire**B**ug right?

Comment: Are the key-pair-id items tied to a browser specific instance? Another commenter mentioned that you could simply wget this url, but I had problems grabbing the src url from the command line.